# Android : Fragment error on getview.findviewbyid?

Tags: android, view, fragment

I'm developing an application of a music player in fragment. Here when i used  the code to get views from XML it stopped working.

My xml code is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMusicList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/default_album_art_thumb"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewMusic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutPlayingSong"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewAlbumArt"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/small_image_art_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/small_image_art_width" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textNowPlaying"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/empty_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/small_button_width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/small_button_width"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_previous" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/small_button_width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/small_button_width"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_play"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnPause"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/small_button_width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/small_button_width"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_pause" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/small_button_width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/small_button_width"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_stop" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/small_button_width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/small_button_width"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_next" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnMusicPlayer"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/small_button_width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/small_button_width"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_music" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textBufferDuration"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textDuration"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment code is ..

```
public class Device_Main extends Fragment {

    Device_CustomAdapter deviceCustomAdapter = null;
    static TextView playingSong;
    Button btnPlayer;
    static Button btnPause, btnPlay, btnNext, btnPrevious;
    Button btnStop;
    LinearLayout mediaLayout;
    static LinearLayout linearLayoutPlayingSong;
    ListView mediaListView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView textBufferDuration, textDuration;
    static ImageView imageViewAlbumArt;
    static Context context;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_activity_main, container, false);



        context = Device_Main.this.getActivity();
        init();

        //<--------------------------------------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>.
        return view;
    }


    private void init() {
        getViews();
        setListeners();
        playingSong.setSelected(true);
        progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        if(Device_PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST.size() <= 0){
            Device_PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST = Device_UtilFunctions.listOfSongs(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        }
        setListItems();
    }

    private void setListItems() {
        deviceCustomAdapter = new Device_CustomAdapter(this,R.layout.device_custom_list, Device_PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST);
        mediaListView.setAdapter(deviceCustomAdapter);
        mediaListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    }

    private void getViews() {
        playingSong = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textNowPlaying);
        btnPlayer = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnMusicPlayer);
        mediaListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listViewMusic);
        mediaLayout = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutMusicList);
        btnPause = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
        btnPlay = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        linearLayoutPlayingSong = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutPlayingSong);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        btnStop = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        textBufferDuration = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textBufferDuration);
        textDuration = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textDuration);
        imageViewAlbumArt = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageViewAlbumArt);
        btnNext = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnPrevious = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    }

    private void setListeners() {
        mediaListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item, int position, long id){
                Log.d("TAG", "TAG Tapped INOUT(IN)");
                Device_PlayerConstants.SONG_PAUSED = false;
                Device_PlayerConstants.SONG_NUMBER = position;
                boolean isServiceRunning = Device_UtilFunctions.isServiceRunning(Device_SongService.class.getName(), getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                if (!isServiceRunning) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),Device_SongService.class);
                    context.startService(i);
                } else {
                    Device_PlayerConstants.SONG_CHANGE_HANDLER.sendMessage(Device_PlayerConstants.SONG_CHANGE_HANDLER.obtainMessage());
                }
                updateUI();
                changeButton();
                Log.d("TAG", "TAG Tapped INOUT(OUT)");
            }
        });

        btnPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Device_Main.this.getActivity(),Device_AudioPlayerActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Device_Controls.playControl(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            }
        });
        btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Device_Controls.pauseControl(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            }
        });
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Device_Controls.nextControl(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            }
        });
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Device_Controls.previousControl(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            }
        });
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Device_SongService.class);
                context.stopService(i);
                linearLayoutPlayingSong.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        imageViewAlbumArt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Device_Main.this.getActivity(),Device_AudioPlayerActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try{
            boolean isServiceRunning = Device_UtilFunctions.isServiceRunning(Device_SongService.class.getName(), getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            if (isServiceRunning) {
                updateUI();
            }else{
                linearLayoutPlayingSong.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            changeButton();
            Device_PlayerConstants.PROGRESSBAR_HANDLER = new Handler(){
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                    Integer i[] = (Integer[])msg.obj;
                    textBufferDuration.setText(Device_UtilFunctions.getDuration(i[0]));
                    textDuration.setText(Device_UtilFunctions.getDuration(i[1]));
                    progressBar.setProgress(i[2]);
                }
            };
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void updateUI() {
        try{
            Device_MediaItem data = Device_PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST.get(Device_PlayerConstants.SONG_NUMBER);
            playingSong.setText(data.getTitle() + " " + data.getArtist() + "-" + data.getAlbum());
            Bitmap albumArt = Device_UtilFunctions.getAlbumart(context, data.getAlbumId());
            if(albumArt != null){
                imageViewAlbumArt.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(albumArt));
            }else{
                imageViewAlbumArt.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(Device_UtilFunctions.getDefaultAlbumArt(context)));
            }
            linearLayoutPlayingSong.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }

    public static void changeButton() {
        if(Device_PlayerConstants.SONG_PAUSED){
            btnPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public static void changeUI(){
        updateUI();
        changeButton();
    }



}
```

Log Catt is..

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.jithin.myapplication.Device_Main.getViews(Device_Main.java:83)
                                                                                  at com.example.jithin.myapplication.Device_Main.init(Device_Main.java:66)
                                                                                  at com.example.jithin.myapplication.Device_Main.onCreateView(Device_Main.java:58)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:608)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:570)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:551)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2008)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1025)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:995)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1272)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1377)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
```

Can anyone help me find a sollution for this error .. Thank You ......

Comment: Put findviewByID under view with view.findViewById(); in OncreateView method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fragment getView() method will be null since the view on OnCreate is not returned to activity before initializing those views.

First pass the view object to init function.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_activity_main, container, false);
        context = Device_Main.this.getActivity();
        init(view);
        return view;
    }
```

Now pass the view object to getViews() method from init function

```
private void init(View view) {
        getViews(view);
        setListeners();
        playingSong.setSelected(true);
        progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        if(Device_PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST.size() <= 0){
            Device_PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST = Device_UtilFunctions.listOfSongs(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        }
        setListItems();
    }
```

Now use the view object to use findViewById()

```
private void getViews(View view) {
        playingSong = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textNowPlaying);
        btnPlayer = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnMusicPlayer);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `getView()` method before the `View` is created. Move the `init()` method in `onViewCreated()`.

Answer (score 1):

`getView()` remains `null` until you do `return view;` in your `onCreateView()`
and since you do  `init();`, which calls `getViews();`, which calls  `getView()` before `return view;`, it will produce NPE.
Solution can be for example moving this lines

```
context = Device_Main.this.getActivity();
init();
```

into `onActivityCreated()`

Answer (score 1):

pass the view to init() method (Ex: init(view) ) and from there pass to getViews() method (Ex:  getViews(view)).

use that view in getViews() code,

```
 playingSong = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textNowPlaying);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling init() from onCreateView(), while onCreateView() must only contain code to inflate view layout for Fragment. By this time getView() method will return null as it is not initialized.

You must move all your initialization code (init()) to methods called later in fragment lifecycle i.e. onActivityCreated().

refer: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html for fragment lifecycle.